# Use object property as array index returns error (C++)

Tags: c++, class, constants

I have a C++ class named `Matrix` which has a row and column property:

```
class Matrix
{
public:
    int rows, cols;
    float elements[36];
    // some methods, including constructor
}
```

I also have a separate function that is supposed to add the elements of two `Matrix` objects together and return a third `Matrix`.  The code is:

```
Matrix MatAdd(const Matrix& inMat1, const Matrix& inMat2)
{
    float elements[inMat1.rows*inMat2.cols];  // returns error
    // other code ...
}
```

The actual error I get is the following (I'm on VS 2013):

```
error C2057: expected constant expression
```

I've tried casting `inMat1.rows` to a `const int`, but I still get the same error.  I must be misunderstanding some core C++ concept, but I haven't been able to find any help by online searches.

Thanks,
R.

Comment: The error message from the compiler is clear. `inMat1.rows*inMat2.cols` is not a constant expression. You cannot use it to create an array of `float`s on the stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you cannot define a variable length array. The length needs to be known at compile time.

A work work around is dynamically allocating the array.

`float* elements = new float[inMat1.rows*inMat2.cols];`

You will also have to change the `elements` member of your `Matrix` class.

Comment: `std::vector<float> elements;` is a much better idea than `float *elements`, it is less error-prone and requires you to write much less support code.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Thanks for the correction. [Some C99 standards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) are in C++11 but not variable length arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The size of array should be constant:

```
    int a1[10]; //ok
    int a2[SIZE]; //ok if the value of SIZE is constant/ computable in compile time
```

You can use vector to avoid this error. You can also allocate memory dynamically according to your need.